# XSLT : Apply a template to place child nodes into distinct table columns

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a novice on XML transformation and I'm currently working on a XSLT file. I want to place each "person" element , to a different row and its child nodes (name,acct-no,fav-color ), to the distinct columns of each row ,in the table I have created in the first template. I'm applying the second template that matches the "person" element so for each person element a table row and its cells can be inserted.

Here is my XML file.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
        <?xml-stylesheet href="people.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
        <people>
         <list-name>Favorite Colors</list-name>
         <person>
           <name>
            <first>Bob</first>
            <last>Toddson</last>
           </name>
           <acct-no>327598</acct-no>
           <fav-color hex="#ff0000">Red</fav-color>
        </person>
        <person>
           <name>
            <first>Red</first>
            <last>McBlue</last>
           </name>
           <acct-no>209890</acct-no>
           <fav-color hex="#00ff00">Green</fav-color>
       </person>
       <person>
          <name>
            <first>Tammy</first>
            <last>Yu</last>
          </name>
          <acct-no>978541</acct-no>
          <fav-color hex="#7fff00">Chartreuse</fav-color>
       </person>
       <person>
          <name>
           <first>Phillip</first>
           <last>Cardwell</last>
          </name>
          <acct-no>258929</acct-no>
          <fav-color hex="#d2b48c">Tan</fav-color>
      </person>
     </people>
```

And the XSL file.

```
    <xsl:template match="/">

     <head>
        <title> People Report: <xsl:value-of select="/people/list-name" />
        </title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <center>
        <h1> People Report: <xsl:value-of select="/people/list-name" /> </h1>
      </center>

      <table border="1" align="center">
       <tr>
         <td>Last Name</td>
         <td>First Name</td>
         <td>Account Number</td>
         <td>Favorite Color</td>
       </tr>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="/people/person" />
      </table>

    </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="person">
 <tr>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="name/last" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="name/first" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="acct-no" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="fav-color" />
  </td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current output places all person elements and its child nodes only in the first row-first column of the table. I thought that my problem was due to not using the for-each command and the apply-templates inside, so it can iterate on every person element. As I have read in related posts here in SE the apply-templates command would apply for each person element, thus making the use of for-each not necessary in my case. I've been struggling for a couple of hours now and I can't see or understand where I'm missing something, so any help would be appreciated .

Expected Output :

[image]

Output I get :

[image]

Thanks a priori.

Comment: Can you post the output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: "*My current output places all person elements and its child nodes only in the first row-first column of the table.*" Are you sure? Using your input and your stylesheet, I get a 4x4 table with everything in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <head>
            <title> People Report: <xsl:value-of select="/people/list-name" />
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <center>
                <h1> People Report: <xsl:value-of select="/people/list-name" /> </h1>
            </center>

            <table border="1" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td>Account Number</td>
                    <td>Favorite Color</td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="/people/person">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name/last" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name/first" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="acct-no" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="fav-color" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>

        </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to the root element of the stylesheet, as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

to make sure all result elements in all templates are created as XHTML elements.

Then for me the complete sample http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014030901.xml renders fine in IE 10 and current versions of Firefox and Opera.

Comment: I added it to the root element of the stylesheet as you mentioned,now i'm only getting the first person element in the right position. I've both tried IE 10 and Firefox [on Windows 7] but still I have the same output as I recently edited on my post. Maybe it's a configuration problem with Dreamweaver(CS6)?

Comment: Does the example http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014030901.xml not render correctly for you? If you still have problems then post a URL to a complete sample so that others can reproduce the problem.